# Issue after up-gradation to 21.0.1

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I have upgraded ag-grid version in my Project to version 21.0.1. Here i am facing one issue in "getColumnState()". I am saving user preferences when user drags and drops the column to change its position in the table. Here i am using onGridReady(param) function to call save param to a global variable and then using it like variablename.getColumnState().
This is giving me the array having properties like "colId".  When i am doing setColumnState() with this saved data, on console i am getting warning as "ag-grid: column 'ABC' not found" here 'ABC' is some field associated to one of the grid columns.  Also there is some '_1' getting added to each of these field values like if the original field was 'ABC' the getColumnState() is returning 'ABC_1".
Please suggest what can cause this or is there any changes in API in updated version. 
My project is in angular 5.

Answer (score 0):

After carefully going through the documentation of AG-Agid, I have seen that the parameters require for Data table are 'headreName', 'field'.
But for setting and getting column state, we need column id this works fine in previous versions but in new version when the DOM is created this fails. As the preference is first given to column Id then to 'field'.